# Isn't the whole concept of prophetism unjust?

Tags: jannah, prophets

As far as I know, the prophets will go directly to the paradise. Since it is God who chooses them, then how is this just ? Isn't it unfair for others who are not chosen by the God ?

Sure prophets encountered many troubles and hardness during their lifetimes but aren't those temporary since they knew that they will go to paradise even before they die ?

Comment: We don't know if all prophets will go to paradise.  Every nation had a prophet and there were literally thousands of them.  We only know about a couple that God praised.

Comment: Aren't prophets sinless according to the Islam ? How  could a sinless person go anywhere but heaven ? However, If you think that some prophets may have sinned then please bring some evidences that support that claim as it is a serious one.

Comment: It's a disputed issue if Prophets were sinless.  I don't believe they were sinless because there are prayers that ask for forgiveness.

Comment: I've always been told that all of them are sinless and will go directly to the heaven. Could you point me to some sources that say otherwise ? Really interesting to hear what you say.

Comment: And there's no evidence that shows Prophets were sinless.

Comment: Well, in the Quran we read about Prophets/Messengers asking God for forgiveness and repentance.  It would be pointless for them to do that if they wee already sinless.  Here's an example of Prophet Noah: “Noah said: ‘O my Lord! I seek refuge with You from asking You that of which I have no knowledge. And unless You forgive me and have Mercy on me, I would indeed be one of the losers.’” (Quran Hood 11:47)

Comment: Just google Are prophets sinless and you'll find many sources that say they are. Their credibility is an another issue. The question is: Is there an Islamic source that claims that prophets can sin and therefore go to hell ?

Comment: Prophet David: "… and he sought Forgiveness of his Lord, and he fell down prostrate and turned in repentance.” (Quran 38:24)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36930/discussion-between-sayyid-and-spiderrico).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Whoever does righteousness - it is for his [own] soul; and whoever does evil [does so] against it. **And your Lord is not ever unjust to [His] servants.** [Qur'an [41:46]](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=41&verse=46)*

---

> *Those who reject Our Ayat (proofs, evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.) are deaf and dumb in darkness. Allah sends astray whom He wills and **He guides on the Straight Path whom He wills.** [Qur'an [6:39]](http://quran.com/6/39)*
>
> *And whoever obeys Allah and the Messenger - those will be with the ones upon whom Allah has bestowed favor of the prophets, the steadfast affirmers of truth, the martyrs and the righteous. And excellent are those as companions. [Qur'an [4:69]](http://quran.com/4/69)*

In another verse (which I'm unable to find right now), I believe it says something like *the Prophets, the believers are the one who are successful.*

There are many ways which God describes in the Qur'an to enter paradise, why don't you look at them? Perhaps, **God will guide the righteous people more and [eases their path towards paradise](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=92&verse=7).**

Allah knows the best.

Comment: "God will guide the righteous people more and eases their path towards paradise". I've no objection to that. I truly believe that God makes things easier for people who are righteous. However, we become righteous by our actions which we decide by our free will. It seems like to me that prophets are chosen to be righteous right from the beginning.

Comment: In another Hadith (if I remember it right) Prophet said, the ones who are most tested by God are the prophets, then those near to God. @SpiderRico

Answer (score -1):

All praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

**Hasnaa’ bint Mu’aawiyyah from Bani Suraym said: my paternal uncle told me: I said, O Messenger of Allaah, who will be in Paradise? He said: Prophets will be in Paradise, martyrs will be in Paradise, infants will be in Paradise and baby girls who were buried alive will be in Paradise. Narrated by Imaam Ahmad**

Yeah Prophets are the people of Paradise without any doubts in Islam.It is not unjust at all as what Allah Swt knows we are unaware of it,no one on the whole universe is able to reach upto his knowledge and wisdom.It is one of the obligatory belief in Islam that Prophets are trustworthy and preserved from sin.

Imam Al-Ghazali writes in his work Rawda-tut-talibin:
It is established by consensus (ijma) that the Messenger of Allah is free of committing grave sins, venial sins, and makruhs. It is also established by consensus that he is free of forgetfulness, negligence, and making a mistake and erring in the messages he conveys.

If there have been some occurences seem to be errors not suitable to their diginity was to teach and explain the religion to their followers.

A Scholar has mentioned that because the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him and give him peace) was continually rising in degrees to higher stations, the previous, lower station in relation to the higher station was akin to a sin with respect to him. And others have said that his seeking forgiveness was simply to establish a sunna for his community as he (Allah bless him and give him peace) was free and exalted from sin. [Biqa`i, Nazm al-Durar fi Tanasub al-Ayat wa al-Suwar; al-Suyuti/al-Mahlli, Tafsir al-Jalalayn]

> Now Suppose if some one doesnt think about Prophets (the Chosen ones)
>   as people of Paradise *Nauzubilaah min Zalik* what could be the
>   consequences ----
>
> --To think them  that they could do any sins by disobeying Allah Swt which could lead them to hell Nauzubilaah.Which is Negating this verse of Quran
>   **"And We did not send any messenger except to be obeyed by permission
>   of Allah ."(4:64)**
>
> --They could perform any sin so they are not perfect enough to send messages from Allah Swt to their followers.Then followers could have
>   doubtful in their teachings and orders Nauzubillah.Negating this verse of Quran
>   **"Nor does he speak out of his own desire"(53:3)"O you who have
>   believed, obey Allah and obey the Messenger and do not invalidate your
>   deeds.(By disobeying him)"(47:33),He who obeys the Messenger has
>   obeyed Allah;(4:80)**
>
> --So followers would be doing sins as well by following prophets who are sinners Nauzubillah.Allah SWt says **"So be patient for the decision
>   of your Lord and do not obey from among them a sinner or ungrateful
>   [disbeliever].(Quran 76:24)**
>
> --So followers have no perfect guidance at all to seek the path to Allah Swt Nauzubilaah negating **"And those who disbelieved say, "Why has a sign not
>   been sent down to him from his Lord?" You are only a warner, and for
>   every people is a guide."(13:7)It is He who has sent His Messenger
>   with guidance and the religion of truth to manifest it over all
>   religion, (9:33)**
>
> --So there would be no hope for salvation for followers if Prophets are going to hell,whom should people follow then if they have no
>   perfect role models Nauzubilaah ,negating **"And indeed, you are of a great moral
>   character. "(68:4) "Say, [O Muhammad], "If you should love Allah, then
>   follow me, [so] Allah will love you and forgive you your sins. And
>   Allah is Forgiving and Merciful."(3:31)**

There is a beautiful wisdom of Allah swt that he elected prophets as chosen ones as people of pardise ,It is offcourse for you,me and other followers so that we could become people of Paradise too In Sha Allah by following their teachings and path.

One Scholars has mentioned in regard of some question" It is advisable not to approach the status of Prophethood with inquiries except with the highest good manners. Prophets are the elect of the Creator and like or above the angels in rank. We should take care, also, to focus on what is vital to our salvation and relinquish pursuits that are not only irrelevant but actually damaging to faith and works."

Allah Swt is the "Just" Creator, Who never commits any injustice against His creation.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: So basically you say take it as it is. Right ?

Comment: So basically I say take it as it is said by Allah Swt by our Prophet peace be upon him and by consensus not as our selfmade logics because Islam means to submit or surrender ourselves , our knowlege is limited we can not challenge Quran o hadith it could lead anyone to misguidance.

Comment: I was not challenging anything but was merely trying to understand the reasoning behind it. But of course, our minds are limited.

Comment: MashAllah ,yeah I could understand its fine to think for the reasons too with proper manners thats why our scholars also came into the field of philosophy and logic.JazakAllah